# How to make 2 different validation message work separately within the same textbox in a grid view in ASP.NET (ASPX)?

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have added more than one validation error message for each text box in the gridview.

This is the code I have used:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="80px" DataField="Product_Price" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:0.00}",Eval("Product_Price"))%>'/>
<asp:Label ID="Label4" Text="AUD" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID ="Button11" runat="server" OnClick="Price_Update_Click" ValidationGroup="UpdatePrice" CommandArgument="Button11" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0.09" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Currency" ValueToCompare="0.09" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers with only 2 digits after decimal" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>          
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="60px" DataField="Product_Quantity" Text='<%#Eval("Product_Quantity")%>' />
<asp:Button ID ="Button12" runat="server" OnClick="Quantity_Update_Click" ValidationGroup="UpdateQuantity" CommandArgument="Button12" CommandName="Update"  Text="Update" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Integer" ValueToCompare="0" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Numbers only but no decimals" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>      
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In order to test **TextBox3**, these are the values I have tested:

**Scenario 1:** I enter 0.00,
                I get the following error message: "Must be greater than 0.09"

**Scenario 2:** I enter 0.08,
                I get the following error message: "Must be greater than 0.09"

**Scenario 3:** I enter 0.09,
                I get the following error message: "Must be greater than 0.09"

**Scenario 4:** I enter 1, 
                I get the following error message: "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimals"

**Scenario 5:** I enter 250,
                I get the following error message: "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimals"

**Scenario 6:** I enter 1.555,
                I get 2 error messages at the same time: "Must be greater than 0.09" "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimals."

**Scenario 7:** I enter abcd,
                I get 2 error messages at the same time: "Must be greater than 0.09" "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimals."

Therefore, for **TextBox3**, based on what I have entered for **Scenario 6** and **Scenario 7**  .. I want to get only one error message which is "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimals."

In order to test **TextBox4**, these are the values I have tested:

**Scenario 1:** I enter 0, I get the following error message: "Must be greater than 0"

**Scenario 2:** I enter 0.5, I get 2 error messages at the same time: "Must be greater than 0" "Numbers only but no decimals"

**Scenario 3:** I enter 10.5, I get 2 error messages at the same time: "Must be greater than 0" "Numbers only but no decimals"

**Scenario 4:** I enter abcd, I get 2 error messages at the same time: "Must be greater than 0" "Numbers only but no decimals"

Therefore, for **TextBox4**, based on what I have entered for **Scenario 2**, **Scenario 3** and **Scenario 4** .. I want to get only one error message which is "Numbers only but no decimals."

Hence, for **TextBox3**, I only need to fix **Scenario 6** and **Scenario 7**.

On the other hand, for **TextBox4**, I only need to fix **Scenario 2**, **Scenario 3** and **Scenario 4**

If there is any minor mistake in my .aspx code, then it would be helpful if the recommended syntax solution is provided.

Comment: Create a CustomValidator with all the needed checks.

Comment: Would be helpful and easier to understand if you can show it in one line CustomValidator syntax at least for TextBox3 :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/f5db6z8k.aspx has a good example

Comment: My suggestion is a bit off topic for your question, but you should consider adding some javascript to do input masking, always having 2 decimals. Even when someone enters 150, that it auto displays: 150.00 and therefor makes one of the validators not needed anymore.

Comment: @VDWWD ... The link that you gave me, does that mean that I have to remove CompareValidator and RegularExpression Validator and replace it with CustomValidator ?

Comment: Depends on your exact needs. But you can have multiple validator for one input.

Comment: @VDWWD ... My need is to prevent firing of CompareValidator message and RegularExpressionValidator message at the same time ... Which is the best approach ? ... 1. Remove CompareValidator and RegularExpressionValidator and just keep CustomValidator only .. OR .. 2. Add CustomValidator along with CompareValidator and RegularExpression Validator ... What do you suggest ?

Comment: If they contradict each other it is best to create everything in a CustomValidator. IN there you can combine both.

Comment: @VDWWD ... Just now I tried - <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"  ErrorMessage="Must be greater than 0.09" Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Currency" ValueToCompare="0.09" ErrorMessage="Numbers with only 2 digits after decimal"
           ValidationExpression="^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$"></asp:CustomValidator>    ... But when I'm testing it, now it is not showing any validation error message at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property in all the validator "Display = Dynamic" and try it

Comment: Both in CompareValidator and RegularExpressionValidator, I added Display = Dynamic and it is still showing both the error messages. For example, in TextBox 3 if I'm entering 1 then it is showing single error message: "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimal" which is perfectly OK and if I'm entering 1.555 then it is showing 2 error messages: "Must be greater than 0.09" "Numbers with only 2 digits after decimals." which I need to fix it by showing 1 error message only.

Comment: You can use the custom validator and it will be easy for you